# How to customize the Picker?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I wonder if you have how to remove the text and add an icon in this component?

https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#picker-def-headref

I wanted it to look like this ... how can I modify using the native-base I have to do manually?

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Content, Picker, Form } from "native-base";

export default class PickerExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: "key1"
    };
  }
  onValueChange(value: string) {
    this.setState({
      selected: value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <Form>
            <Picker
              note
              mode="dropdown"
              style={{ width: 120 }}
              selectedValue={this.state.selected}
              onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
            >
              <Picker.Item label="Wallet" value="key0" />
              <Picker.Item label="ATM Card" value="key1" />
              <Picker.Item label="Debit Card" value="key2" />
              <Picker.Item label="Credit Card" value="key3" />
              <Picker.Item label="Net Banking" value="key4" />
            </Picker>
          </Form>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I used https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu

Answer (score 1):

recently i faced this issue. but can not resolve by picker item.
i used

> react-native-searchable-dropdown

package. you can customize this package and add icon.

Comment: but I do not need a Searchable Dropdown

Comment: you can disable search option